# How to redirect the page when some condition reached in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In the following code when the if condition is true then it should go to google.com but is isn't. I wanted the window to go to google.com as the ok in the alert box is pressed why this isn't working? What is the best way to do it?

```
 if(("admin"===userid)&&("admin"===psw))
       {   
           window.alert("Logged in Successfully!!!");
           window.location.href="https://www.google.co.in";
           x=x+1;
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: @Sumedh what is the relation of your link with the question(besides the `window.location.href`) ?

Comment: The link describes two ways to open a url, one of which is used by OP.Also, the answer there,explains in detail about each of the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(("admin"===userid)&&("admin"===psw)){
    var r = confirm("Logged in Successfully!!!");
    if( r == true ){
        window.location.href="https://www.google.co.in";
        x=x+1;

    } else {
        // non redirect stuff here 
    }       
}
```

Research: [jQuery: how to open a dialog window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395536/jquery-how-to-open-a-dialog-window) (Answer 2)